# Identify single member to serialize for entire class in Json.NET

Tags: asp.net, serialization, json.net

I want to make a class that will serialize to one of its members.

Take a helper class that switches between a string and a function:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class FunctionOrString {
    object JSONObject { get { return (((object)ValFunction) ?? ValString); } }
    public string ValString { get; set; }
    public Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JRaw ValFunction { get; set; }
}

class ClassToSerialize {
    [JsonProperty("template")] public FunctionOrString Template { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to output `{ "template": { "JSONObject": "val" } }`, but `{ "template": "val" }`. Which attribute(s) do I need to apply to the `FunctionOrString` class or the `JSONObject` property so that the `Template` object will serialize itself as the serialization of the `JSONObject` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_1.htm) to change the shape of the serialized JSON.  Something like this should do the job:

```
class FunctionOrStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(FunctionOrString);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, ((FunctionOrString)value).JSONObject);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it you can add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your class like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FunctionOrStringConverter))]
class FunctionOrString
{
    ...
}
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oIkhXg

Note: In your question the `JSONObject` property is not marked `public`.  I am assuming this was an accidental omission.  If not, you will either need to make it `internal` or use reflection to get its value within the converter.